# Cannot run CUDA kernel : too many resources requested for launch

Tags: cuda

Take a look on my self written cuda kernel. I had a big kernel but it returned me error message. Then I simplified it and found that it fails on one loop. I simplified this loop and found that if I use int value or constant value to fill data[threadIdx.x] in loop it works fine. But if I use double type value it returns an error.

**Advice**: if you are not correctly coping your data from host to device, you can get "warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaLaunch returned (0x7)" message when you use Nsight or you can get segmentation fault error when you run your app from terminal

```
__global__ void sumSeries(double* dSum,int* totalThreadNumber){
    volatile  __shared__ double data[768];
    double var=0;
    data[threadIdx.x]=0;
    for ( int i = 10 ; i < 20 ;++i){
        var=i;
        data[threadIdx.x] += (var)/(var*var+1);
        __syncthreads();
    }


}
```

**Why it does not work?**

```
int main() {

    int threadsPerBlock=768;
    int blockCount=8;

    int *hostThreadNumber=new int ;
        *hostThreadNumber=threadsPerBlock*blockCount;
    int* deviceThreadNumber=NULL;

    double* deviceSum=NULL;
    double* hostSum=(double*)malloc(blockCount);


    cudaError_t cuerr=cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig(cudaFuncCachePreferShared);
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess){
        std::cout<<"Cant SetCacheConfig: "<<cudaGetErrorString(cuerr)<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cuerr=cudaMalloc(&deviceSum,blockCount*sizeof(double));//размер дабла*число блоков
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess){
        std::cout<<"Cant allocate memory for deviceSum: "<<cudaGetErrorString(cuerr)<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cuerr=cudaMalloc(&deviceThreadNumber,sizeof(int));
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess){
        std::cout<<"Cant allocate memory for deviceThreadNumber: "<<cudaGetErrorString(cuerr)<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cuerr = cudaMemcpy(deviceSum,hostSum,blockCount*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess){
        std::cout<<"Can not copy hostSum to device: "<<cudaGetErrorString(cuerr)<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cuerr = cudaMemcpy(deviceThreadNumber,hostThreadNumber,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess){
        std::cout<<"Can not copy hostThreadNumber to device: "<<cudaGetErrorString(cuerr)<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    sumSeries<<<dim3(blockCount),dim3(threadsPerBlock)>>>(deviceSum,deviceThreadNumber);
    cuerr=cudaGetLastError();
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess){
        std::cout<<"Cuda kernel error: "<<cudaGetErrorString(cuerr)<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cuerr= cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess){
        std::cout<<"Can not synchronize cuda kernel : "<<cudaGetErrorString(cuerr)<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cuerr= cudaMemcpy(hostSum,deviceSum,blockCount*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess){
        std::cout<<"Can not copy data to host: "<<cudaGetErrorString(cuerr)<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cudaFree(deviceSum);
    cudaFree(deviceThreadNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the exact error you are having ? and could you provide a full sample ? with the number of threads / blocks you are launching?

Comment: Please, specify also the specific card you are working with.

Comment: I'm using 768 threads per block and 8 blocks. My GPU is GeForce® GTS 450. Full sample consists of 2 parts(cuda kernel and main function(I have just added it))

Comment: warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaLaunch returned (0x7)

Comment: What happens when you add a `#pragma unroll 1` directly before the `for` loop of your kernel?

Comment: Cannot currently run cuda code, but I see some errors in your code. `double* hostSum=(double*)malloc(blockCount);` allocates only 8 bytes, because of `int blockCount=8;`. But you call `cudaMemcpy(deviceSum,hostSum,blockCount*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);` that will copy 64 bytes of memory from `hostSum` to `deviceSum`!

Comment: As an addition, you can pass single int, float, double values direct as an parameter from host to your kernels! There is no need to allocate separate global memory for them! - `int N = 10; kernel<<<1,1>>>(N)` works.

Comment: @Marco13, nothing good happens. "warning: Cuda API error detected: cudaLaunch returned (0x7)"

Comment: @hubs, yes. You were correct. Thats why I had that error. Thank you for that advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just allocated 8 bytes memory for `hostSum`

```
double* hostSum=(double*)malloc(blockCount)
```

That's wrong if I assumed that you want to allocate `blockCount * sizeof(double)` bytes for it, because you allocate this amount of memory for `deviceSum` and uses it for the memory copy between host and device.

```
cuerr = cudaMalloc(&deviceSum,blockCount*sizeof(double));

cuerr = cudaMemcpy(deviceSum,hostSum,blockCount*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cuerr= cudaMemcpy(hostSum,deviceSum,blockCount*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```